# Query CloudantClient with ComplexKey returns a null key

Tags: cloudant

I'm using CloudantClient 2.11 . I created a view with a complex key.
I'm trying to query the view using the client API . i can see each row result has both the key and the value returned but row.getKey() returns null.

[my database view and documents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJVHK.jpg)

[with reduce and grouping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pK6Oc.jpg)

my code looks like this:

```
ViewResponse<ComplexKey, Integer> response =  database.getViewRequestBuilder("view", "viewName").newRequest(Key.Type.COMPLEX, Integer.class).reduce(true)
                .group(true).build().getResponse();
        List<Row<ComplexKey, Integer>> rows = response.getRows();
        for (Row<ComplexKey, Integer> row : rows) {
        
            ComplexKey key = row.getKey();
            Integer value = row.getValue();
            
        }
```

the problem is row.getKey() is all ways null although i can see it has the key value.

[key value in bedugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkKND.jpg)

Thank you for the Help

Assi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cloudant Java client only supports array-valued complex keys. It looks as if you're using an object-valued key from your debugger screen shot.

This is stated in the docs, admittedly not super-obvious:

http://static.javadoc.io/com.cloudant/cloudant-client/2.11.0/com/cloudant/client/api/views/Key.ComplexKey.html

and in the code itself, you can see how it's implemented here:

https://github.com/cloudant/java-cloudant/blob/master/cloudant-client/src/main/java/com/cloudant/client/api/views/Key.java#L122

The `null` you're getting comes from here:

https://github.com/cloudant/java-cloudant/blob/master/cloudant-client/src/main/java/com/cloudant/client/api/views/Key.java#L250

Comment: See [this issue comment](https://github.com/cloudant/java-cloudant/issues/386#issuecomment-340009841) for the reasons why array keys are preferred to objects.